# Does the rc folder contain files that start on boot?

Tags: linux, reboot, rc

I created a file in `/etc/rc0.d`, named it `rc.local`.

In this file I added a line that run another file that I had put in `Desktop`.
I did all this so that the command can be run on boot. I followed [the instructions in this article](https://www.2daygeek.com/execute-run-linux-scripts-command-at-reboot-startup/) (the first method), but nothing seems to work.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Could you name your system? It might be using `systemd` without you being aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.d/` mentioned in the instructions you linked is a mostly-historical directory that was once used to group all the start-up script directories together: there would have been `/etc/rc.d/init.d/`, `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/`, `/etc/rc.d/rc1.d` and so on. Most modern distributions have long since chosen to omit the `rc.d` directory and to place the other directories directly under `/etc/`.

`/etc/rc0.d/` is supposed to contain symbolic links to scripts (the actual location of scripts should be `/etc/init.d/`) that should be executed at *system shutdown or power-off*.

`/etc/rc6.d/` is for links to scripts that should be executed at *reboot* (i.e. when shutting down the system with intent to immediately restart again, like after installing a kernel update).

The most appropriate directory for a link to your script would be either `/etc/rc3.d/` or `/etc/rc5.d/`, depending on your system configuration and the default runlevel of your system (if using SysVinit). Linux distributions based on Debian generally use runlevel 3 for normal multi-user state (assuming classic SysVinit), while those based on RedHat/Fedora would use runlevel 5 for multi-user state with GUI login enabled, and runlevel 3 for multi-user state with the local X11 GUI subsystem disabled.

The names of the symbolic links in any `/etc/rc?.d/` directories should begin with either upper-case S or with upper-case K, followed with a (usually) two-digit number to identify the relative placement of the script in the start-up order among other links in that directory. The upper-case S would make the system run the linked script with the command-line parameter `start`, while K would cause the parameter `stop` be used instead.

So, your script should have been placed into `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, and then you should have made one or both symbolic links like this:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/rc.local /etc/rc3.d/S99rc.local
ln -s /etc/init.d/rc.local /etc/rc5.d/S99rc.local
```

But that's not all!

Modern Linux distributions, even those that use classic SysVinit instead of `systemd`, tend to use various solutions to parallelize the execution of various system start-up tasks instead of running them strictly one by one. This is because on modern multi-core CPUs, parallelization will make the boot process much faster. In this case, you should add a specifically formatted comment block at the beginning of your script to define which system services your script depends on, or else the parallelization logic might run the script *too soon*, before the required system services are started first.

If your distribution uses `systemd`, this is especially important, as even some distributions' "factory default" default `rc.local` gets executed quite early in the start-up process unless you add suitable dependency definitions.

See http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html for current specifications of the recommended comment block for SysVinit-style startup/shutdown scripts.

In a nutshell, you might want something like this at the beginning of your `rc.local` script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: rc.local
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: run locally-configured start-up commands
### END INIT INFO
```

In my opinion, the Method-1 in [the instructions you linked](https://www.2daygeek.com/execute-run-linux-scripts-command-at-reboot-startup/) contains incomplete and old advice. The other two methods might be easier for a new user, but don't include instructions on how to determine whether those methods are applicable or not in any given distribution.